# Enviar variável com a função Autocomplete do Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma função Jquery, que ao digitar o nome do produto, ele busca no banco de dados e me traz um array de resultados via json, e com este resultado eu preencho os campos automaticamente.
A função funciona certinho, mas me deparei com uma outra situação, onde tenho que enviar uma outra variável junto.
Abaixo irei postar a parte do código que onde chamo a função autocomplete:

```
$("#nome" + x).autocomplete({
               source: "produtos.php",
               minLength: 2,
              select: function (event, ui) {
              $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
              $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
              $('#ean' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
              }
              });
```

A pagina `produtos.php` esta assim:

```
<?php

 if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

 //$idusuario = $_GET['idusuario'];

 $return_arr = array();

 if ($con) {
            $fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT   
            produtos.idproduto,produtos.nome,produtos.referencia,produtos.ean,produtos.valorvenda,
            produtos.quantidade,produtos.minimo,tabeladepreco.desconto,
            tabeladepreco.modalidade AS 'modalidade'
            FROM produtos,tabeladepreco,usuarios
            WHERE produtos.nome like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_GET['term'])) . "%'
            AND usuarios.modalidade = tabeladepreco.modalidade
            AND tabeladepreco.idproduto = produtos.idproduto
            AND produtos.ativo = 1 ");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
                   $row['nome'] = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
                   $row_array['value'] = $row['nome'] . " | " . $row['modalidade'];
                   $row_array['codigo'] = $row['ean'];
                   $row_array['referencia'] = $row['referencia'];

                   array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
                  }
                }
                mysqli_close($con);

               echo json_encode($return_arr);
             }
          ?>
```

a variavel `idusuario` ja vem declarada e e com valor atribuído a ela no inicio da pagina, só não estou sabendo como colocar ela junto com o  `$("#nome" + x)`pra receber ela no `produtos.php` onde deixei comentado o recebimento dela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#nome").autocomplete({
                  source: "produtos.php?idusuario="+idusuario,
                  minLength: 2,
                  select: function (event, ui) {
                     $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
                     $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
                     $('#ean' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
                  }
   });
```

Comment: Rodrigo, desta forma ele não traz os produtos, quando insiro o nome.
Fiz a seguinte mudanca:
`$.getJSON("produtos.php", { idusuario: idusuario },response);`
Mas mesmo assim não trouxe os produtos.

Comment: Alterei. Faça um teste. No arquivo PHP use $_REQUEST['term']

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo, ficou certinho.